# Why form.io form builder component's custom css class is property not reflecting in the element?

Tags: css, angular, formbuilder, formio, form.io

io in my angular application. I want to change some css for some form builder components.

So, I have tried to add custom css class property for that component as below :

[image]

and I saved the component. But , When i try to inspect the component using dev-tools , the custom css is not available in the element. The default class form-control is avaiable as below :

[image]

Please anyone tell me why it happens and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The custom css class provided will get applied to the div containing the component not to the input field. To apply for the input field, add css like this :

```
    .custom .form-control {
     // custom css goes here
    }
```